# App state in react-native does not remove the listener

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have added the listener in the following way(tried putting in both constructor and componentDidMount):
AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);

And the removed the listener the following way in componentWillUnmount method:

AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);

And in the callback function:

```
  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert('App state: ' + this.state.appState);
      alert('Next App state: ' + nextAppState);
    }, 0);
  }
```

It alerts several times.
Its not removing the listener configured once.
Please let me know if someone is aware of it ?

Comment: I'm also hitting an issue with multiple listeners, but it only happens when I launch the app multiple times

Answer (score 35):

**[According to the latest docs (September 2021 v0.65+) `removeEventListener` is deprecated](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate#removeeventlistener)**

The docs now recommend using the `remove` function on the subscription object (`EmitterSubscription`) which is returned from `AppState.addEventListener`.

Example usage:

```js
const subscription = AppState.addEventListener('change', (appState) => {
  if (appState !== 'active') {
    return;
  }

  // Run custom logic

  subscription.remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the update! However I believe there is a typo on the last sentence, `AppState.removeEventListener` should be `AppState.addEventListener` instead.

Comment: However, it seems that `AppState.addEventListener` doesn't actually return the `remove` method. The example given in the docs doesn't work too.

Comment: Are you on v0.65+? If not this won't work for you.

Also, if you are running this inside a component there is a possibility that you are adding the event listener multiple times. @PoulsQ's answer would probably help you.

Comment: I am using Expo, so I guess they have not added support for the latest version of react native. The old method of using `.removeEventListener` still works however. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I have a typescript error with `remove()` method: `Property 'remove' does not exist on type 'void'. ts(2339)`

Comment: Thanks for sharing, shouldn't `subscription.remove();` be out of the function scope?

Comment: @Arthur - are you sure you have the latest typescript definitions for v0.65+? Another issue could be that the typescript definitions have not been updated.

Comment: @Rafa2602 - no, in my case it was intentional because I wanted to unsubscribe after the event listener ran. In your case you might want to call it when the component unmounts.

Answer (score 19):

You should use API like now on

```
useEffect(() => {
 const myListener = AppState.addEventListener('change', this.someHandler)
 return () => {
   myListener.remove()
 }
}, [])
```

Answer (score 4):

Faced the same issue these last days.
I've finally managed it by deporting my app state management to my App.js component and created a service manager.

Here quickly how my `App.js` look like:

```js
import {AppState } from "react-native";
import {AppStateService} from "YOUR_PATH_TO_THE_NEXT_FILE";

export default function App() {

    // Listen to app state
    AppStateService.init();
    useEffect(() => {
        AppState.addEventListener('change', AppStateService.getInstance().handleAppStateChange);
        return (() => {
            AppState.removeEventListener('change', AppStateService.getInstance().handleAppStateChange);
        })
    }, []);

    return (/*Rendering stuff (navigation, error boundary, ...*/);
}
```

`AppStateService.js`:

```js
/**
 * Class to allow us to refer to the app state service
 */

export class AppStateService {

    static instance;

    static STATE_ACTIVE         = 'active';
    static STATE_INACTIVE       = 'inactive';
    static STATE_BACKGROUND     = 'background';
    static STATE_NOT_LAUNCHED   = 'not_launched';

    previousState   = AppStateService.STATE_NOT_LAUNCHED;
    currentState    = AppStateService.STATE_ACTIVE;

    handlers = {};

    appLaunchId = 0;

    /**
     * @returns {AppStateService}
     */
    static getInstance() {
        if(!this.instance){
            this.instance = new AppStateService();
        }

        return this.instance;
    }

    static init = () => {
        // This func need to be call in the App.js, it's just here to create the instance
        const instance = AppStateService.getInstance();

        instance.appLaunchId = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    }

    handleAppStateChange = (nextState) => {
        if(nextState !== this.currentState) {
            this.previousState = this.currentState;
            this.currentState = nextState;

            for (const [key, handler] of Object.entries(this.handlers)) {
                handler(nextState);
            }
        }
    }

    getCurrentState = () => {
        return this.currentState;
    }

    getPreviousState = () => {
        return this.previousState;
    }

    addStateHandler = (key, handler) => {
        this.handlers[key] = handler;
    }

    hasStateHandler = (key) => {
        if( this.handlers[key] ){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    removeStateHandler = (key) => {
        delete this.handlers[key];
    }
}
```

and now here is how to call it from anywhere you want in your app components:

```js
export default class RandomComponent extends React.Component {
    
    componentDidMount() {
        // Check app going background or not
        this.handleAppStateChange = this.handleAppStateChange.bind(this);
        AppStateService.getInstance().addStateHandler('myListenerCustomKey', this.handleAppStateChange);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // Remove app state change listener
        AppStateService.getInstance().removeStateHandler('myListenerCustomKey');
    }

    handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
        console.log("I'm going to be -" + nextAppState + "- while I was -" + AppStateService.getInstance().getPreviousState() + "-");
    }
}
```

This way you have the capability to listen everywhere in your app to the app foreground/inactive/background state and correctly subscribe/unsubscribe to those events.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using a class component by the looks of your code. The way I ended up solving it was by creating a pointer function that points to the actual function inside the scope of `this`, without using `.bind(this)`.

E.g.

```js
// Actual Function    
handleAppStateChange(state) {
  // Work your magic!
}

// Pointer
handleAppStateChangeCall = (state) => this.handleAppStateChange(state);

// Setup listener event
setupAppStateListener() {
  AppState.addEventListener("change", this.handleAppStateChangeCall);
}

// Clear listener event
clearAppStateListener() {
  AppState.addEventListener("change", this.handleAppStateChangeCall);
}

// Mounted Hook
componentDidMount() { 
  setupAppStateListener();
}

// Unmount Hook
componentWillUnmount() {
  clearAppStateListener()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the listener from `ComponentWillUnmount` function

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }
```

Comment: I used it the same way. Still it does not work. Shows the alerts multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Set state is an Async process. So in componentWillUnmount don't use it as the component get unmount and still for that scene the setState is in process causing the alert.

Comment: So, what do you suggest, how should this be un-registered ?

Answer (score 0):

May be caused by a change in the function you are listening on

```
this.props.navigation.addListener(
  'didFocus',
  () => {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange)
  }
)
this.props.navigation.addListener(
  'willBlur',
  () => {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange)
  }
)
```

it work normal

```
this.props.navigation.addListener(
  'didFocus',
  () => {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange.bind(this))
  }
)
this.props.navigation.addListener(
  'willBlur',
  () => {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange.bind(this))
  }
)
```

it not work
so maybe you need like this

```
this.handleAppStateChange = this.handleAppStateChange.bind(this)
```

in your constructor

Answer (score 0):

We can change code as follow:

useEffect(() => {
const stateListener = AppState.addEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);

```
return () => {
  stateListener.remove();
};
```

}, []);

const handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
if (appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
console.log('App has come to the foreground!');
setConnectStatus(true);
} else {
console.log('App has come to the background or inactive!');
setConnectStatus(false);
}

```
appState.current = nextAppState;
setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
console.log('AppState is ', appState.current);
```

};